# Meetup.com API event time to date?

Tags: ruby

When I hit a meetup group on Meetup.com to find upcoming events I end up with this fragment of JSON that I believe is when the next meetup is scheduled.

```
"utc_offset": -21600000,
"time": 1415752200000,
"waitlist_count": 0,
"updated": 1382991416000,
```

I'm trying to convert this to a humanized Date/Time in Ruby, but I'm not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the time stamps here were in milliseconds. Divide them by 1000 and ruby can convert the seconds to Time.

You can use `Time.at(i)` in Ruby to convert integer to Time.

```
Time.at(1415752200000/1000) # => 2014-11-12 08:30:00 +0800
Time.at(1382991416000/1000) # => 2013-10-29 04:16:56 +0800
```

For more info, see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Time.html#method-c-at

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your `time` object its return only time(in miliseconds) not date.

For that you can try this using **[strftime](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime)** method with `Time` class

```
seconds = 1415752200000/1000
Time.at(seconds).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
 => "06:00:00"
```

As per your requirement you can modify formatting of `strftime()` method like

```
Time.at(seconds).strftime("%Y-%B-%d %H:%M:%S")
 => "2014-November-12 06:00:00"
```

**Available Formatting Options:**

```
%a - The abbreviated weekday name (“Sun”)

%A - The full weekday name (“Sunday”)

%b - The abbreviated month name (“Jan”)

%B - The full month name (“January”)

%c - The preferred local date and time representation

%d - Day of the month (01..31)

%H - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock (00..23)

%I - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock (01..12)

%j - Day of the year (001..366)

%m - Month of the year (01..12)

%M - Minute of the hour (00..59)

%p - Meridian indicator (“AM” or “PM”)

%S - Second of the minute (00..60)

%U - Week number of the current year, starting with the first Sunday as the first day of the first week (00..53)

%W - Week number of the current year, starting with the first Monday as the firstday of the first week (00..53)

%w - Day of the week (Sunday is 0, 0..6)

%x - Preferred representation for the date alone, no time

%X - Preferred representation for the time alone, no date

%y - Year without a century (00..99)

%Y - Year with century

%Z - Time zone name

%% - Literal “%” character
```